# how to check if given path is pointing to existing file OR directory?

Tags: c++, file, winapi, path, directory

I need a function that simply returns bool if there is an entity at the given path, no matter if file or directory. What function to use either in winapi or stl ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`GetFileAttributes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa364944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will return information about a file system object which can be queried to determine if it is a file or directory and it will fail with if it does not exist.

For example:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (2 == argc)
    {
        const DWORD attributes = GetFileAttributes(argv[1]);
        if (INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES != attributes)
        {
            std::cout << argv[1] << " exists.\n";
        }
        else if (ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND == GetLastError())
        {
            std::cerr << argv[1] << " does not exist\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cerr << "Failed to query "
                      << argv[1] 
                      << " : "
                      << GetLastError()
                      << "\n";
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is [`PathFileExists`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb773584%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (shlwapi)

> Determines whether a path to a file system object such as a file or
>   folder is valid.

(Caveat for UNC shares)

Comment: Also, the 260 character path name length limit is not just a theoretical restriction. Alternatives with less restrictive implementations can be found in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14006215/1889329).