# C++ PathFileExists limited to 260 chars

Tags: c++, winapi

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773584%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) `PathFileExists()` function only supports filepath < 260

I want to check if a path exists on a remote location. Now legally I can create a file whose name is 256 letters long, when I add server name to it, the total length exceeds 260 and so `PathFileExists()` cannot work with it.

What other option do I have to check for file existance?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842411/how-to-check-if-given-path-is-pointing-to-existing-file-or-directory/13842472#13842472

Comment: I will try that and see if it works for me, but i would still prefer to use a direct method to check existence rather than this indirect way. There has to be an API which will handle long paths

Comment: Equivalently, call `FindFirstFile`. Since you're just interested in one file, don't call `FindNextFile`. "Find" is pretty direct IMO.

Comment: The curse of C strings and MAX_PATH is pretty rampant.  The native Windows operating system supports paths up to 32,766 characters, you put `\\?\\` in front of the win32 path name to turn it into a native path name.  But you'll have to pick and choose the api functions carefully, PathFileExists() is MAX_PATH encumbered.  Kernel32 functions are fine.

Comment: +1 @HansPassant, you should answer that question! :-D

Comment: I'll pass.  Explaining these kind of things just draws the anger of users that run into this limitation.  They do shoot the messenger around here.

Answer (score 4):

Since all [Shell Path Handling Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773559.aspx) are limited to `MAX_PATH` - 1 characters you will have to use kernel32 functions instead if you need to support longer file names. Your options are:

1. [FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418.aspx)
2. [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858.aspx)
3. [GetFileAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364944.aspx)

While [FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418.aspx) is fairly straight forward you are required to call [FindClose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364413.aspx) if the function does not return an error code. This triggers an additional network round-trip if you are querying for a file on a network. The additional network round-trip is also triggered for [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858.aspx) where you have to cleanup the `HANDLE` calling [CloseHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724211.aspx). Plus it may give the [wrong answer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/10/23/5612082.aspx).

The remaining option to use [GetFileAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364944.aspx) is the suggested way to query for file existence if you need to support file names longer than `MAX_PATH` characters.

Comment: GetFileAttributes will return me attributes even when a directory path is passed. I wont be able to distinguish between file and directory.

Comment: @Nitin `bool isDirectory = ( GetFileAttributes( pathName ) & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY ) != 0;`

Comment: One small addition to your method. Make sure to also check for symbolic links, or for the `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT` flag. It should be off for a "true" directory. And also make sure to check for `INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES` that `GetFileAttributes` may also return.

Comment: On WIn7 x64 I noticed using SysInternals Process Monitor that `GetFileAttributes` results in three operations (Open, Query, Close). Whereas `PathFileExists` results in only one.

Comment: @MrTux: That may well be the case, but the comparison isn't very helpful. `PathFileExists` could be a bazillion times faster than any of the alternatives posted in this answer, but you cannot use it if you need to support path names longer than 260 characters. This question is specifically asking for path names longer than 260 characters.

Comment: Your answer implies that FindFirstFile and Create file both open and close a handle and that GetFileAttribute doesn't.

Comment: @MrTux: I was talking about the **additional** network round-trip, that the `FindClose` and `CloseHandle` calls produce. `GetFileAttributes` obviously needs to open and close a file handle as well to implement its functionality. But it doesn't require two distinct calls to do so.