# Check if file existing or not in c

Tags: c, file, winapi, widechar, lpcwstr

1. prgchDirPath is char pointer. But expected is LPCWSTR.
   How to change this?
2. prgchDirPath is a directory path. **File is not existed**.
   But I want to make sure if directory/path exists or not.
   Can the API below helps me? if yes, how?

   ```
   unsigned char IsFilePathCorrect(char* prgchDirPath)
   {
           WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
           HANDLE handle;
           int found=0;

           //1. prgchDirPath is char pointer. But expected is LPCWSTR.
           //How to change this?
           //2. prgchDirPath is a directory path. File is not existed.
           //But I want to make sure if directory/path exists or not.
           //Can the API below helps me? if yes, how?
           handle = FindFirstFile(prgchDirPath, &FindFileData);
           if(handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
           found = 1;
           if(found) 
           {
               FindClose(handle);
           }
           return found;
   }
   ```

I want to check if directory path is existed or not. Please provide one sample code. Thank you.

Comment: Try calling the narrow version of FindFirstFile, `FindFirstFileA`, and use the narrow version of the structure, `WIN32_FIND_DATAA`

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks allot. I could pass char pointer directly now. But problem is, I passed "C:\\" and '&FindFileData' to this API and it gave return code 0xFFFFFFFF, that means not found right? The path C:\ existed in my local drive.

Comment: It means not found because that isn't the *directory*, its just a path to one. You're not finished yet. Try `"C:\\."`

Comment: @WhozCraig You are right, I created a directory called 'xx' and gave path as `"C:\\xx"` and it worked. But I also tried giving `"C:\\."`, but it did not work.

Comment: If you want to check if a drive letter exists you can use `GetLogicalDrives`.

Comment: The answer is in a different question: [C++ `PathFileExists` limited to 260 chars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13877994/c-pathfileexists-limited-to-260-chars).

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `access`, which is widely supported on Windows, Linux, Mac, etc: `access(filepath, 0)` returns `0` if file exists, and error code otherwise. On Windows, you will need to `#include <io.h>`.

Answer (score 0):

How about doing it like this using [getAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function:-

```
BOOL DirectoryExists(LPCTSTR szPath)
{
  DWORD dwAttrib = GetFileAttributes(szPath);

  return (dwAttrib != INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES && 
         (dwAttrib & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY));
}
```

or you can try this too:-

```
#include <io.h>     // For access().
#include <sys/types.h>  // For stat().
#include <sys/stat.h>   // For stat().

bool DirectoryExists( const char* path){

    if( _access( path, 0 ) == 0 ){

        struct stat s;
        stat( path, &s);

        return (s.st_mode & S_IFDIR) != 0;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the path is correct or not without using any Windows API as shown below

```
    /*
     * Assuming that prgchDirPath is path to a directory
     * and not to any file.
     */
    unsigned char IsFilePathCorrect(char* prgchDirPath)
    {
        FILE *fp;
        char path[MAX_PATH] = {0};

        strcpy(path, prgchDirPath);
        strcat(path, "/test.txt");

        fp = fopen(path, "w");
        if (fp == NULL)
            return 0;

        fclose(fp);
        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: And if the directory path is valid but the file `"test.txt"` isn't there?

Comment: @WhozCraig - You are right, the second argument should be "w" instead of "r". Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Even changing it to `"w"` isn't going to work if you don't have write-permission on the folder. You need a non-intrusive method.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<fcntl.h>

#define DEVICE "test.txt"

int main()
{
    int value = 0;
    if(access(DEVICE, F_OK) == -1) {
        printf("file %s not present\n",DEVICE);
        return 0;
    }
    else
        printf("file %s present, will be used\n",DEVICE);
    return 0;
}
```